# Why virtual inheritance cause pointer offset?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, virtual-inheritance

I know that multiple inheritance and virtual functions cause a pointer offset when casting the derived class pointer to base class pointer due to memory layout.

However I cannot figure out why virtual inheritance can also cause this effect? What I only know about virtual inheritance is to prevent multiple instances of same class.

Below is my code.

```
class X 
{
public:
    int i;
};

class Y :virtual  public X 
{
    int j;
public:
    void vf(){};
};

int main()
{
    Y* py = new Y;
    X* px = (X*)py;

    cout<<py<<endl;
    cout<<px<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. That's clearly not C code.

Comment: value of px is different from value of py

Comment: "can also cause this problem?": it is not a problem, is it ?

Comment: Can we see the output ?

Comment: the reason is how your compiler implements the virtual inheritance (to solves the multiple inheritance of the same class, because this is the reason of virtual inheritance)

Comment: Explain why you think a pointer offset is a problem in this case.   It's one thing to suggest that there is (effectively) only a single `X` in a `Y`, and another to suggest the `X` and the `Y` should be at the same address.   Imagine what would happen if there were multiple virtual bases `X1`, `X2`, etc of `Y`   - are you really suggesting that the address of a `Y` should be equal to the address of all the `X1`, `X2`, etc????

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's certainly not a problem. But it's an interesting effect that I cannot explain right away. I think, I'm going to suggest an edit of the question.

Comment: To gain more insight: Also print the addresses (or relative offsets) of the two variables within the object. The gaps will show where the vtable pointers are located.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know. So what?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, I can guess. I might be wrong, and I'm ready to be told so by the OP. I was confident enough to gamble, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct Base {
  long a;
};

struct Derived : virtual public Base {
  long b;
};

int main() {
  Derived object;
  intptr_t reference = (intptr_t)&object;
  printf("Base offset: %" PRIdPTR "\n", (intptr_t)(Base*)&object - reference);
  printf("a offset: %" PRIdPTR "\n", (intptr_t)&object.a - reference);
  printf("Derived offset: %" PRIdPTR "\n", (intptr_t)(Derived*)&object - reference);
  printf("b offset: %" PRIdPTR "\n", (intptr_t)&object.b - reference);
}
```

produces the following output on my machine (Debian/g++):

```
Base offset: 16
a offset: 16
Derived offset: 0
b offset: 8
```

Thus, the layout of the object is this:

```
+------+------+------+
| vptr |  b   |  a   |
+------+------+------+

              | Base |

|      Derived       |
```

As you see, the compiler has not allocated a `vptr` to the class `Base`. This is required by the standard because `Base` is a POD (Plain Old Data) type without any virtual features. The `Derived` class must contain a `vptr` because it has a virtual base. As such, **it is impossible for the compiler to put the `vptr`-less `Base` subobject at the very beginning of the `Derived` object because it needs to place a `vptr` at that location in memory**.

Comment: The vptr (if it exists) does not have to come first. It has to be at a fixed offset in the `Derived` object, so that the compiler can find it. Back in the olden days the location of the vptr varied. When Microsoft introduced COM, it was COM that required the vptr to be at the front, and C++ compilers that hadn't been doing that were changed so they would work with COM.

Comment: @PeteBecker I remember that on (classic) Mac OS (68000 or 1st gen PowerPC), Metrowerks CodeWarrior had the vptr at one end of the object and Symantec "THINK C"/C++ at the other (I don't remember which was which though).

Comment: @curiousguy — Borland’s compiler originally put the vtable at the end of the base class’s data. It moved to the front when we added COM support.